# How do I read each line?

Tags: java, loops, file, int, addition

I'm trying to add the total of each row, but I can only compute the first row total? How do I make it so that the program goes and reads each line to compute the total?

Once I do that...I want to put a if else statement in there. I want it to ask each row if there is an int that is above 30,000. For each int that is above 30,000 I want the total to add 1,000.

```
package finalProg;


    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class test
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          readFromFile("sales.txt");
       }

       private static void readFromFile(String filename)
       {
          LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = null;
          try
          {
             //Construct the LineNumberReader object
             lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));


             //Setting initial line number
             lineNumberReader.setLineNumber(0);



             //Read all lines now; Every read increase the line number by 1
             String line = null;
             while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null)
             {
                System.out.println("Store " + lineNumberReader.getLineNumber() + ": " + line);

                File inputFile = new File("sales.txt");
              Scanner a = new Scanner(inputFile);
                int jan = a.nextInt();
                int feb = a.nextInt();
                int mar = a.nextInt();
                int apr = a.nextInt();
                int may = a.nextInt();
                int jun = a.nextInt();
                int jul = a.nextInt();
                int aug = a.nextInt();
                int sept = a.nextInt();
                int oct = a.nextInt();
                int nov = a.nextInt();
                int dec = a.nextInt();

                System.out.println(jan + feb + mar + apr + may + jun + jul + aug + sept + oct + nov + dec + "\n");

             }

          } 
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          } finally
          {
             //Close the LineNumberReader
             try {
                if (lineNumberReader != null){
                   lineNumberReader.close();
                }
             } catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
             }
          }

       }


       }
```

```
20000 35000 23000 50000 45000 24000 41000 39000 36000 42000 41000 39000
35000 42000 38000 41000 50000 51000 53000 50000 54000 55000 54000 56000
20000 10000 15000 12000 13000 14000 13000 14000 15000 19000 20000 21000
44000 45000 46000 42000 44000 48000 47000 46000 44000 43000 48000 49000
33000 34000 35000 36000 40000 41000 42000 40000 44000 42000 41000 39000
50000 53000 51000 52000 55000 56000 52000 54000 51000 56000 55000 53000
```

So far the output looks like this:

```
Store 1: 20000 35000 23000 50000 45000 24000 41000 39000 36000 42000 41000 39000
435000

Store 2: 35000 42000 38000 41000 50000 51000 53000 50000 54000 55000 54000 56000
435000

Store 3: 20000 10000 15000 12000 13000 14000 13000 14000 15000 19000 20000 210000
435000

Store 4: 44000 45000 46000 42000 44000 48000 47000 46000 44000 43000 48000 49000
435000

Store 5: 33000 34000 35000 36000 40000 41000 42000 40000 44000 42000 41000 39000
435000

Store 6: 50000 53000 51000 52000 55000 56000 52000 54000 51000 56000 55000 53000
435000
```

Comment: Looks like input and output files are redundant in your code. Also, you don't use `BONUS()` in your `main()` void.

Comment: And could you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work: does it throw an error/exception or it doesn't work properly?

Comment: @coder-coder how do I add BONUS() to my main method?

Comment: I can't seem to get anything to output...earlier I was getting my sales.txt file to print but then when I started trying to add up the ints, it got all wonky.

Comment: Looks like you've made several changes since the last review.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that this works better, but of course now I have another set of issues. How do I tell it to compute the sum for each line?

Comment: If you are having a new issue now please ask a new question, lets keep the questions clean and talking of only one issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better to declare `jan`, `feb` etc. variables out of the method because it really looks like that values are not refreshed.
But I would recommend you something like this:

```
public class test(){
  private int sum;

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      readFromFile("sales.txt");
   }

  //You don't need this void to be static!
  private void readFromFile(String filename){
    LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = null;
      try
      {
         //Construct the LineNumberReader object
         lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));


         //Setting initial line number
         lineNumberReader.setLineNumber(0);



         //Read all lines now; Every read increase the line number by 1
         String line = null;
         while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null)
         {
            System.out.println("Store " + lineNumberReader.getLineNumber() + ": " + line);

            File inputFile = new File("sales.txt");
          Scanner a = new Scanner(inputFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
      sum =+ a.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum = 0;
         }

      } 
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally
      {
         //Close the LineNumberReader
         try {
            if (lineNumberReader != null){
               lineNumberReader.close();
            }
         } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

   }


   }
```

This should be better.

Comment: Correct me if something is wrong, and I'll edit it.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm a bit confused what this is taking place of? Do you mind telling me what it would be better replacing?

Comment: I inserted my corrections into your code, there can be odd brackets, but it should generally work now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be done differently here.

- First off, consider dropping the idea of using two specific data file
  readers. There is no point in this when only one file reader will do.
  Take your pick and stick with it.
- Whichever file reader you decide to use, make sure you close it when
  done.
- Don't open your data file with a new instance of a reader for every
  iteration of a **while** loop. You're creating a hook onto that file
  every time you do that and it will remain there until each reader
  instance is closed or your application ends.

Declaring 12 specific int variables to hold monthly values can be best suited with the use of an Array. You need to also consider the fact that there could possibly (just possibly at some point) be a typo or error within the data which will not produce a valid integer value. This could throw a real wack-a-doodle into the workings of your code if not handled.

Below is some code that demonstrates one way you can accomplish the task at hand. It is well commented so you can see what is going on:

```
// Create a months header string for display purposes.
    String header = String.format("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s", 
                                  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
                                  "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    // Create a header underline for display purposes.
    String underline = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "="));
    //Display a 'Start' underline for the Console display.
    System.out.println(underline);

    // Read the 'sales.txt' data file for monthly data of 6 stores.
    // Trap the 'FileNotFoundException'.
    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("sales.txt"))) {
        int storeCounter = 0;   // Keep track of the Store count.
        long overallTotal = 0;  // Maintain an Over-All total for all Stores
        String line;            // Used to hold current read in line data
        // Iterate through the data file one line ata a time...
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            line = reader.nextLine().trim();              // Trim leading/trailing whitespaces from read line.
            if (line.equals("")) { continue; }            // Skip blank lines (if any).
            /* Split the line data into a String[] Array. 
               "\\s+" is used to split on one (or more) 
               whitespaces.                         */
            String[] lineMonths = line.split("\\s+"); 
            int yearTotal = 0;                            // Keep track of the line's yearly total.
            storeCounter++;                               // Increment the Store Counter by 1.
            int monthsOver30000 = 0;                      // Number of Months over 30000.
            System.out.println("Store: " + storeCounter); // Display the Current Store Number in Console.
            System.out.println(header);                   // Display the months header line in console.
            // Display the current Store's monthly data in Console...
            for (String month : lineMonths) { 
                // Display the current month.
                System.out.printf("%-8s ", month);
                // Add the current month value to the Yearly Total
                // but first make sure it is in fact a valid integer
                // value otherwise ignore it (don't add it to yearly).
                if (month.matches("\\d+")) {
                    int monthValue = Integer.parseInt(month); // Convert the month value from string to integer
                    // Is the month value more than 30,000?
                    if (monthValue > 30000) {
                        // Yes, so add 1,000 to the Month Value
                        monthValue += 1000;
                        monthsOver30000++;
                    }
                    yearTotal += monthValue;

                }
            }

            System.out.println();  // Add a newline to all the above printf's.

            // If there were months that were over 30,000...
            if (monthsOver30000 > 0) {
                // Display information about it in Console.
                System.out.println();  // Add a newline to separate this section.
                System.out.println("There were " + monthsOver30000 + " months "
                        + "for this Store where Monthly values were over 30000"
                        + " therefore " + (monthsOver30000 * 1000) + " was added "
                        + "to the");  
                System.out.println("Yearly Total.");
                System.out.println();  // Add a newline to separate this section.
            }

            System.out.println("Yearly Total: -->   " + yearTotal);  // Display the yearly total in Console.
            System.out.println(underline);  // Display a underline so as to start a new data line.
            // Add the current Year Total to the All Stores Over-All
            // Total. Will be used for averaging later on.
            overallTotal += yearTotal;
        } // Continue iterating through data file until end of file is reached.

        // Display the over-all total for all Stores Yearly totals in Console.
        System.out.println("The over-all total for all " + storeCounter + " Stores: --> " + overallTotal);
        // Display the yearly average for all stores contained within the data file.
        System.out.println("The yearly average for all " + storeCounter + " Stores: --> " + overallTotal/storeCounter);
    }
    // Catch the 'FileNotFoundException' exception (if any).
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // Display the Exception message if the exception was thrown.
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Based on the data you provided in your post, the outputto Console should look something like this:

```
===========================================================================================================
Store: 1
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec     
20000    35000    23000    50000    45000    24000    41000    39000    36000    42000    41000    39000    

There were 9 months for this Store where Monthly values were over 30000 therefore 9000 was added to the
Yearly Total.

Yearly Total: -->   444000
===========================================================================================================
Store: 2
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec     
35000    42000    38000    41000    50000    51000    53000    50000    54000    55000    54000    56000    

There were 12 months for this Store where Monthly values were over 30000 therefore 12000 was added to the
Yearly Total.

Yearly Total: -->   591000
===========================================================================================================
Store: 3
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec     
20000    10000    15000    12000    13000    14000    13000    14000    15000    19000    20000    21000    
Yearly Total: -->   186000
===========================================================================================================
Store: 4
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec     
44000    45000    46000    42000    44000    48000    47000    46000    44000    43000    48000    49000    

There were 12 months for this Store where Monthly values were over 30000 therefore 12000 was added to the
Yearly Total.

Yearly Total: -->   558000
===========================================================================================================
Store: 5
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec     
33000    34000    35000    36000    40000    41000    42000    40000    44000    42000    41000    39000    

There were 12 months for this Store where Monthly values were over 30000 therefore 12000 was added to the
Yearly Total.

Yearly Total: -->   479000
===========================================================================================================
Store: 6
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec     
50000    53000    51000    52000    55000    56000    52000    54000    51000    56000    55000    53000    

There were 12 months for this Store where Monthly values were over 30000 therefore 12000 was added to the
Yearly Total.

Yearly Total: -->   650000
===========================================================================================================
The over-all total for all 6 Stores: --> 2908000
The yearly average for all 6 Stores: --> 484666
```